# How to scroll GridView with page

Tags: flutter, gridview, scrollcontroller

I have a gridview builder like this and in this gridview builder im scrolling posts with page;

```
GridView.builder(
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemCount: listt.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () =>
          navigateToDetail(listt[index]),
      child: Hero(
        tag: (listt[index]["foto"] != null)
            ? NetworkImage(
                listt[index]["foto"])
            : AssetImage(
                "assets/images/n_image.jpg"),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment
                    .spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 7,
                child: Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment
                            .topCenter,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius
                                  .only(
                            topLeft: Radius
                                .circular(
                                    10),
                            topRight: Radius
                                .circular(
                                    10),
                          ),
                          child: (listt[index]
                                      [
                                      "foto"] !=
                                  null)
                              ? OptimizedCacheImage(
                                  imageUrl:
                                      listt[index]
                                          [
                                          "foto"],
                                  imageBuilder:
                                      (context, imageProvider) =>
                                          Container(
                                    height:
                                        double.infinity,
                                    width: double
                                        .infinity,
                                    decoration:
                                        BoxDecoration(
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                      image:
                                          imageProvider,
                                      fit: BoxFit
                                          .cover,
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                  placeholder:
                                      (context, url) =>
                                          Container(
                                    height:
                                        double.infinity,
                                    width: double
                                        .infinity,
                                    decoration:
                                        BoxDecoration(
                                      color:
                                          Colors.grey[400],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Image(
                                  height: double
                                      .infinity,
                                  width: double
                                      .infinity,
                                  fit: BoxFit
                                      .cover,
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                      "assets/images/n_image.jpg"),
                                ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight:
                          Radius.circular(
                              10.0),
                      topLeft:
                          Radius.circular(
                              10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight:
                            Radius.circular(
                                10.0),
                        bottomLeft:
                            Radius.circular(
                                10.0),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  child: Center(
                    child: AutoSizeText(
                      "${listt[index]["name"]}",
                      textAlign:
                          TextAlign.center,
                      style:
                          GoogleFonts.lora(
                        textStyle:
                            TextStyle(
                          color: Colors
                              .grey[700],
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight:
                              FontWeight
                                  .w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                      maxLines: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

In this gridview builder I can scroll the page the way I want like this;

[image: First Gridview]

When I add `controller: scrollController,` in my Gridview builder to listen controller, scrolling change to this;

[image: Second Gridview]

I have to add `controller: scrollController,` to my Gridview to listen controller for paginaiton so I cant remove controller, so how can I scroll page like first example with adding `controller : scrollController,`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the physics to

`physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in your `GridView.builder()`.

Comment: When I add physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() in my GridView page only scroll as long as the page height so its not working.

Comment: Gridview should scrollable but it should scrollable when tab bar reach to top like my first Scroll

Comment: Can you share your body code?

Comment: When I copied the code to send you, I tried to add the controller to the nested gridview in the body and I solved my problem, you helped indirectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I add controller to my NestedGridView in the body instead of GridView Builder and I solved my problem.